# ¿Cómo crear una factory Bean en Spring sin usar condiciones?

Tags: java, spring

tengo clase abstracta de un vehiculo

```
public abstract class Vehiculo(){

  public String consumo(){
     return "";
  }       
}
```

luego tengo otras dos que heredan camión donde cambia el return de consumo y otro vehiculo.

Quiero hacerlo con factoryBean de Spring
tengo esta clase

```
@Configuration
public class VehiculoFactoryAppConfig {

 private String id;


 @Bean(name = "vehiculo")
 public VehiculoFactory(){
     VehiculoFactory factory = new VehiculoFactory();
     factory.setId(this.id);
     return factory;
 }

@Bean
public vehiculo() throws Exception{
    return vehiculoFactory().getObject();
}
```

}

la clase factory es así:

```
@Data
public class vehiculoFactory implements FactoryBean<Vehiculo> {

private String id;
private Class clase;
@Override
public vehiculo getObject() throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    vehiculo vehiculo= null;
    if(this.id.equals("1")){
        vehiculo= new Camion();
    }
    if(this.id.equals("2")){
        vehiculo= new Coche();
    }

    return vehiculo;
}

@Override
public Class<?> getObjectType() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    return vehiculo.class;
}

@Override
public boolean isSingleton() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

}
```

¿quería saber si hay alguna manera de obtener de manera automática las clases dependiendo del id sin tener que hacer un if o switch case? 
Muchas gracias.

Comment: Antes de meterte con Spring, convendría que repasaras el Java básico. Los constructores no trabajan tal como tienes implementado *VehiculoFactory()*

Comment: ¿cuál es el problema de esa implementacion?

Comment: Ni *VehiculoFactory()* ni *vehiculo()* son legales. No son constructores porque no tienen el mismo nombre de la clase, no son métodos porque no definen el tipo de retorno. El código que muestras ni siquiera compila.

Comment: eso ya está corregido, sabes si es posible return diferentes clases según un atrbuto sin hacer un if o switch? gracias